# How to get small amount of data rather than complete data on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume I have a collection entry of 100000.
So What is the approach to get only 50 data every time rather than 100000, Because calling the whole dataset is foolishness.
My Dataset is kind of this type:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2e282417d0b91708fa83b5"),
    "post" : "Hello world",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2017-12-11T06:39:32.035Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Like what are the techniques I have to append on my query?

```
//What filter I have to add.?
db.collection.find({}).sort({'createdate': 1}).exec(function(err, data){ 
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({'createdate': 1}).skip(0).limit(50).exec(function(err, data){ 
    console.log(data); 
});
```

there are two more ways to use pagination
one is mongoose-paginate npm module link :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate

seconnd is aggregation pipeline with $skip and $limit options
eg:

```
//from 1 to 50 records
db.col.aggregate[{$match:{}},{$sort:{_id:-1}},{$skip:0},{$limit:50}];
//form 51 to 100 records
db.col.aggregate[{$match:{}},{$sort:{_id:-1}},{$skip:50},{$limit:50}];
```

Comment: Okay. So after getting 50 data, I want to fetch data from 51 to 100, and then from 101 to 150 and so on. So what's the concept for getting these kinds of data

Comment: .skip(50).limit(50), then .skip(100).limit(50), etc. Seems obvious to me from this answer :)

Comment: Hey, Shubham Your solution is absolutely fine but have one problem. First, we have to sort the data. If not sort before then skip result will not the exact one. I was checking so many times. Anyways, thanks

Comment: that is the only way I know but you can make sorting and matching efficient using proper indexes example-->https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

**using limit with find,**

```
db.collection.find().limit(3)
```

**Using limit with aggregate,**

```
db.collection.aggregate({$limit : 2})
```

usually aggregate is used if we need to get the pipe lined out, for example we need to to have `limit` and `sort` together, then

```
// sorting happens only on the pipelined out put from limit.
db.collection.aggregate([{$limit : 50},{"$sort": {_id: -1}}]);

// . operator - sorting happening on entire values even though it comes last. 
db.collection.find().limit(50).sort({_id:-1});
```

The same with added `skip` to get offset

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$limit : 50},{ $skip : 50 },{"$sort": {_id: -1}}]);

db.collection.find().skip(50).limit(50).sort({_id:-1});
```

Comment: So according to your answer after getting 50 data, I want to fetch data from 51 to 100, and then from 101 to 150 and so on. So what's the concept for getting these kinds of data

Comment: i think, `skip` will do your work, i have added that too in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to sort the data and then do limit and skip function.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$sort": {f2: -1}, {$limit : 2}, { $skip : 5 }}]);
```